# Create Events between two dates in ios

Tags: ios

I want to create events of between two dates like that 2015/10/01 to 2015/10/05 create event between two dates

Comment: Are you using `EventKit` framework?

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE explain in brief ?

Comment: yes i m using Eventkit framework

Comment: i m using this program please check it this link https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui and i m not create event in calendar

Comment: thanks for this code but this method is  which add in file

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

-(void)yourmethodToSaveEvent {
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[self checkForEventAuthorization:eventStore completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title = @"title";
        event.startDate = [NSDate date]; // start date
        event.endDate = [NSDate date]; // end date ;
        event.notes = @"notes";
        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err;
        BOOL isSuccess = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        if(isSuccess) {
            NSLog (@"your event saved successfully.");

        } else {
            NSLog (@"failed.");
        }
    }
}];
 }

-(void)checkForEventAuthorization:(EKEventStore *)eventStore completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL granted, NSError *error))block {
 if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
         // iOS 6 and later
     [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
         block (granted,error);
     }];
 } else {
     block (YES,nil);
 }
}
```

Comment: please check this link and this program add event of two dates please help me https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui